# what is the right location for .js.flow in flowtype?

Tags: flowtype

say you have a package, and also a .js.flow file prepared for the various declarations, and you commit it to a .git repo, what is the right location for the .js.flow? I know copy it into flow-typed folders works, but is there a way no need to do that? just npm install, and Flow locates .js.flow file? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the same directory as the source file. If you have foo.js you should have foo.js.flow in the same directory for consuming projects.  (Searched around to find the docs for this and can't find it, I hope someone else can post a link).

Comment: does not work in my testing, if i put myservice.js.flow in flow-typed/, it works, but if I put it under node_modules/myservice, it won't